# JavaFX no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Alguém sabe como instalar o JavaFX no eclipse? Tentei encontrar na internet, mas n encontrei nada util.

Se alguem puder ajudar agradeço.

Versão do eclipse: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Obs: Estou usando o JDK 8u65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acesse o menu Help a opção Install New Software...[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela seguinte, preencha o campo Work with com o endereço conforme imagem.
Pressione Enter e então serão listadas as opções abaixo, conforme imagem.
Selecione a primeira opção: e(fx)clipse - install e clique no botão Next, nas telas seguintes você deve aceitar os termos de uso, e então a instalação deve ser concluída. Deve solicitar que o Eclipse seja reiniciado, reinicie e após isso deve aparecer a opção para criação de um projeto Java FX, se não estiver na primeira opção, procure na opção Other.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: deu certo, obrigado!!